# Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint even no foreign keys are added

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, foreign-keys

**Laravel 8**

For some reason my staging environment will not allow me to run migrations.

I get the following error.

```
General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (
SQL: create table `login_credentials` (
`id` char(36) not null, 
`username` varchar(75) not null, 
`confirmation_code` varchar(36) null, 
`deleted_at` timestamp null, 
`remember_token` varchar(100) null, 
`created_at` timestamp null, 
`updated_at` timestamp null) 
default character set utf8mb4 
collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' 
engine = InnoDB)
```

I do not have any foreign keys defined yet, and this appears to have recently started. I have unit tests written for my application so most of my development is done locally.

Rarely will I upload to the staging server to further test things in more detail before I push to my production. If its a small negotiable change then it'll go from local to production once unit tests pass and verify a clean build. So unfortunately sometime from now and a few weeks ago this became an issue.

my migration file for login_credentials.

```
class CreateLoginCredentialsTable extends Migration
{

    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('login_credentials', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->nullable(false)->unique()->primary();
            $table->string('username',75)->unique();
            $table->string('confirmation_code',36)->nullable()->unique();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

}
```

I have searched high and low on Stackoverflow and have tried the following.

- Verify that my columns for user's `id` match everywhere as a uuid.
- Verify the database is InnoDB
- Verify no foreign keys being defined in any migration
- Verify order of execution is correct on the migration file(s)
- Updated composer to latest dependencies/versions.
- Run all the artisan commands to clear cache, sessions, routes, views, etc.
- Verify my models are $incrementing = false when the id of the tbl is a uuid.
- Move laravel migration files into my migration folder, and add `Cashier::ignoreMigrations(); Passport::ignoreMigrations();` to my appserviceprovider and update those migration files to ensure the user_id isnt bigInt, or Int, and defined as uuid.
- Write a trait to ensure laravel knows the id is a uuid.

Running migration files in my localhost runs fine, without errors.

Any ideas?

Even removed all migration files except for the single login_credentials table and still get the same error? Am I going crazy??
[image]

Comment: I created a migration file and copied your schema and run to debug it from my end, but it ran without errors,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIRrw.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1NND.png, 

so the question now is, what Database are you using, and how did you run your migration

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload` and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My staging, and production databases are on the same mysql server.

Come to find out, you can have a foreign key constraint come from a DIFFERENT DATABASE that has similar, or same table(s) and pose these kind of issues on your database that you're working on.

Answering this rather than deleting it for the rare occasion another person trips across this as a breadcrumb.

"Cannot add foreign key constraint "
CHECK OTHER DATABASES FOR CONSTRAINTS